# Is it possible to inherit auxiliary constructors in Scala?

Tags: scala

I wonder if it is possible to inherit auxiliary constructors in Scala?

I tested this code, and it complained

> temp.scala:18: error: too many arguments for constructor Child: ()this.Child
>
> val a = new Child(42)
>
> ```
>    ^
> ```

```
abstract class Father {
 var value: Int = 0

 protected def setValue(v: Int) = {
  value = v
 }

 protected def this(v: Int) = {
  this()
  setValue(v)
 }
}

class Child extends Father {
}

val a = new Child(42)
```

But if i put

```
protected def this(v: Int) = {
    this()
    setValue(v)
}
```

in the Child class, everything is all right.

Comment: On the evidence you provided, “No”.

Comment: Related question (and answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095329/scala-constructor-overload/1096534#1096534

Comment: Constructors are not inherited. Not in Scala, not in Java. Not primary ones, not secondary ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not, and your example demonstrates why.  You've introduced a mutable variable `value` that may or may not be initialised - depending on the exact constructor used.

This is a potential source for a great many problems, and so Scala made the decision that all object creation should ultimately be directed via the primary constructor, this ensuring consistent initialisation.

If you want `value` to have a default value, then you can specify it as a default parameter (in 2.8+):

```
abstract class Father(val value : Int = 0)
```

or you can use the auxiluary constructor to achieve the same effect in Scala 2.7:

```
abstract class Father(val value : Int) {
  def this() = this(0)
}
```

With `Father` defined in either of the above ways, the following definitions of child are both valid:

```
class Child(v:Int) extends Father(v)

class Child extends Father()
```

You can also make `value` a var if you absolutely have to, but I strongly advise against it.

If the semantics of `value` mean that it's valid to not be initialised, then the correct Scala idiom is to declare it as `Option[Int]`:

```
abstract class Father(val value : Option[Int] = Some(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Child constructor have no parameter and you are trying to instanciate it with one ! You have to declare a parameter in your `Child` constructor and then pass it to the `Father` class, for example:

```
class Child(v:Int) extends Father(v) {
}

val a = new Child(42)
```