# followup about scala constructor oveloading

Tags: scala, constructor, overriding, case-class

This is a followup question to [Scala constructor overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095329/scala-constructor-overload) I'd like a case class constructor that operates on a restricted form of the input and so overrides, rather than overloads the constructor:

```
abstract class Expr

case class RegExpr(regex : Regex) extends Expr {
  override def this(regex : Regex) = {
    if (regex.toString contains "*") 
     throw new Exception("Restricted class of regular expressions: cannot contain Kleene star.")
    else if (regex.toString contains "|")
      throw new Exception("Restricted class of regular expressions: cannot contain disjunction.")
    else this(regex)
  }
}
```

This doesn't compile; I've tried a couple different iterations of this, but they all come back to the compiler telling me it expects 'this', but 'if' is found instead. How do I get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for two constructors. Just add the check inside the class, they will be run at construction time.

```
case class RegExpr(regex: Regex) extends Expr {
   if (regex.toString contains "*") throw ...
   if (regex.toString contains "|") throw ...


}
```

Comment: `require(!regex.toString.contains("*"), "...")` is more idiomatic argument test.

Comment: Also, the final else is unnecessary.