# overloading constructor based on condition in scala

Tags: scala, constructor

i've a simpleNode class with two inputs that u can only fill one of them which are both Map in Scala but i have to check to the type of data in maps in order to fill any of the inputs

the code i've written to do so is:

```
class SimpleNode (
  val uriTriples: collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]] = collection.mutable.Map.empty,
  val valueTriples: collection.mutable.Map[String, Map[String,String]] = collection.mutable.Map.empty
                ) 
  {              
    def this(map:collection.mutable.Map) = {
      map.values.head match {
      case uri : List[String] => this(uris,null) 
      case values : Map[String,String] => this(null,values)
      case _=>
    }
  }
}
```

I always face the error :

```
a:34: error: 'this' expected but identifier found.
[INFO]        map.values.head match {
[INFO]        ^
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095329/scala-constructor-overload

Comment: @Brian , it's what i tried , but no examples seen with switch case so i faced that error

Answer (score 3):

Usual strategy for disambiguation:

```
class SimpleNode (
  val uriTriples: collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]] = collection.mutable.Map.empty,
  val valueTriples: collection.mutable.Map[String, Map[String,String]] = collection.mutable.Map.empty
)
  {
    def this(map:mutable.Map[String, List[String]]) = this(map, null)
    def this(map:mutable.Map[String, Map[String,String]])(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = this(null, map)
}
```

Or a factory is more pedestrian:

```
object SimpleNode {
  def apply(...) = ???
}
```

Comment: isn't the dummyimplicit dupricated in scala ?

Comment: @HadyElsahar Not to my limited knowledge. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$$DummyImplicit

Comment: @HadyElsahar I thought you meant deprecated.