# Logic in an overloaded constructor in scala

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to add some processing logic in an overloaded constructor, but cannot seem to get it working.

Here is a simplified example of what I want to do:

```
class FooBar(val x: String, val y: String) {

    this(z: String) = {
        // DO SOME ARBITRARY CODE
        val x = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
        val y = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
        this(x, y)
    }
 }
```

However, I am getting a compilation error:

```
: 'this' expected but 'val' found
```

This is a very simple task in Java, I would simply set the `x, y` instance variables from 2 separate constructors.

Here is my Java equivalent of what I would like to accomplish:

```
class FooBar {

    public String x;
    public String y;

    public FooBar(String x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public FooBar(String z) {
        // DO SOME ARBITRARY CODE
        this.x = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
        this.y = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
    }
}
```

**=================== EDIT ==================**

I decided to go with @om-nom-nom's approach using a companion object. However as @om-nom-nom pointed out there is no way to get around the missing `new` invocation. Therefore in order to make my constructors consistent, I overloaded the `apply` method in the companion object:

```
class FooBar(val x: String, val y: String)
object FooBar {
    def apply(x: String, y: String) = new FooBar(x, y)

    def apply(z: String) = {
        // DO SOME ARBITRARY CODE
        val x = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
        val y = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
        new FooBar(x, y)
    }
}

FooBar(someX, someY)
FooBar(someZ)
```

Comment: `this(..)` can only be the first call in the constructor.

Comment: @Vulcan I understand that. My question is how can I accomplish my task in Scala, given that restriction? How would you translate the Java code above into Scala?

Comment: As for your edit, you could hide class constructor, so it will be only instantionable from within object: `class FooBar private[FooBar](val x: String, val y: String)`. This way `new FooBar(x,y)` is illegal everywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *usually* done through the companion object (although it is possible to [embed some expression as argument to the first-line-call, as @TheTerribleSwiftTomato shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126947/298389)):

```
class FooBar(val x: String, val y: String)
object FooBar {
    def apply(z: String) = {
        // DO SOME ARBITRARY CODE
        val x = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
        val y = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
        new FooBar(x, y)
    }
}

FooBar(someZ)
```

note that there is no `new` keyword on invocation and there will be no way to overcome this.

Comment: If the OP wants a more overt factory-like notation, rename `apply` to `make`, e.g., then use `FooBar.make("zzzz")`.

Answer (score 2):

Fun fact: your Java "equivalent" is not equivalent per se. Here's something more like it:

```
class FooBar {

    public String x;
    public String y;

    public FooBar(String x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public FooBar(String z) {
        // DO SOME ARBITRARY CODE
        this(x,y);
    }
}
```

This also won't compile, because in Java **and** [in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095329/scala-constructor-overload) any constructor call must be the first statement in an overloading constructor.

However, nothing stops you from using expressions as the argument values of the constructor call, like this:

```
class FooBar(val x: String, val y: String) {

    def this(z: String) = {
        this({"a"+"b"}, {null})
        // DO SOME MORE ARBITRARY CODE
    }
 }
```

**Note that this is not exactly clean code, and a companion object approach, as per om-nom-nom's answer, is more maintainable in general.**

Otherwise, a **direct** conversion from your Java template is only possible if you actually follow that template and use `var` members instead, e.g.:

```
class FooBar() {

    var x: String;
    var y: String;

    def this(x: String, y: String) = {
      this()
      this.x = x
      this.y = y
    }


    def this(z: String) = {
      this()
      // DO SOME ARBITRARY CODE
      this.x = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
      this.y = // SOME ARBITRARY PROCESSING USING z
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, the "Java Equivalent" was not meant to be the exact same as scala, but equivalent in what I am actually trying to accomplish. Correct me if i'm wrong, but from what I know there is actually no way to reproduce my Java code equivalently in Scala.

Comment: @SankethKatta And if you don't believe linked answer, there is a [rule in Scala Language Specification](http://iainmcgin.github.io/scala-ref-markdown/ScalaReference-mathml.html#constructor-definitions): *A constructor expression is either a self constructor invocation [...] or a block which begins with a self constructor invocation.*

Comment: @SankethKatta : Assuming your Java code as the template, and that you're asking about the semantic equivalence of the API of the resulting class, this answer **is** equivalent. You end up with two constructors. And if you really want a direct translation, see my edit. Otherwise, it is as om-nom-nom says: no.

Comment: Thanks guys! I believe it!, I'm just trying to wrap my head around the scala conventions for this scenario. I ended up using the companion object approach, its definitely the most understandable and maintainable.