# Scala constructor how to convert this in Scala language

Tags: java, scala

Hi I need help how to convert this in Scala with two constructor.

```
public class Configure {
  private final Config config;

  public Configure(String confFileName) {
    config = ConfigFactory.load(confFileName);
  }

  public Configure() {
    config = ConfigFactory.load();
  }

  public String getString(String name) {
    return config.getString(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala constructor overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095329/scala-constructor-overload)

Comment: not exactly the same question but is the same concept

Answer (score 1):

```
class Configure(private val config :Config) {
  def this()                     = this(ConfigFactory.load())
  def this(confFileName :String) = this(ConfigFactory.load(confFileName))
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the primary constructor should be private as well for equivalence with Java.

Comment: Why use `private val config` rather than just `config`? What is the advantage of making it a private member rather than just a constructor parameter?

Answer (score 1):

In Scala you would typically do this using a companion object:

```
class Configure private (config: Config) {
  def configString(name: String) = config.getString(name)
}

case object Configure {
  def apply(confFileName: String ) =
    new Configure(ConfigFactory.load(confFileName))

  def apply() =
    new Configure(ConfigFactory.load())
}
```

This nicely separates the behaviour of the class from the different ways of creating it.

[ I renamed `getString` because "getters" don't usually begin with `get` in Scala, they are just the name of the value being retrieved. ]